# Linux command detecting commands before writing to a file

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I'm looking for some command in Linux Shell script which will detect the execution status of a command before writing it into an other file. The code I have consist of a set of commands and after that it log into another with ">" sign. But I want to read the command execution status before ">" sign. Can anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Can you a sample code of what you intend to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you could do. First you can run the bash with `-v` option. This will log the command before executing. Also, you can use `ERR` trap in bash to figure out the exit status of the command.

Example:

```
-> ./err_return_traping.sh 
Command returns 100
./err_return_traping.sh:13 exited with 100

-> cat err_return_traping.sh 
#!/bin/bash

log_failure() {
    declare rs=$?
    echo "$0:$1 exited with $rs"
}

trap 'log_failure $LINENO' ERR

fail_command() {
    echo "Command returns 100"
    return 100
}

fail_command
```